# Rails association - difficulty getting form_for to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I have a Member model that belongs to User

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessible :name
    belongs_to :user

end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessible :name
    has_many :members, :dependent => :destroy

end
```

In my Members controller I have

```
class MembersController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @member  = @user.members.build(params[:member])
    if @member.save
      flash[:success] = "Member created!"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'pages/home'
    end
  end
end
```

In /app/views/users/show.html.erb I have

```
<%= form_for @member do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

But I get the following error:
    undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

```
Extracted source (around line #18):

15: 
16: <h1 class="member">What's up?</h1>
17: 
18: <%= form_for @member do |f| %>
```

My show action in the Users controller is

```
  def show
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      @members = Member.new
      @title = @user.name
  end
```

Which also contains the 'new' method

I have tried changing :user_id to :id in the MembersController but this does not work either. What am I doing wrong here?

thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a `new` action defined in the controller? Is your form located at `/members/new`?

Comment: The Member.new is defined in the show action in the Users controller. The form is located at app/views/users/show.html.erb thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to pass the @user.id as a hidden field in the form, for the association to work!

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `@members = Member.new` by `@member = Member.new` ;-) !

Comment: Do I still need the Member.new line if I am using the build method in the Members controller?  @member  = @user.members.build(params[:member])

Comment: You must glade at nested model if you want to create members in the user class. http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2009/1/26/nested-model-forms